# Do I need to live in Canada to have a bank account in Canada?

Tags: canada, banking, bank-account

I live in the US. I am considering opening a bank account in Canada.

Do I need to live in Canada to have a bank account in Canada?

If so, am I required to file tax in Canada?

Comment: It introduces more filing requirements to American authorities. Canada is the least of your concerns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to live in Canada to open a bank account. However you will have to establish your identity in order to do so.

Having a Canadian bank account does not make you liable for Canadian tax. That would require either being resident in Canada or having Canadian income.